# webpacked failed angular node js

Tags: node.js, angular

I am running a project which is an **angular 4** project but when i try to run it using the command `ng serve --open` it says an error which is ***webpacked failed (error)***

what is the problem? is it on the `nodejs` version ?

Comment: it might be try updating the dependencies. try to ng serve -verbose. Might get you detailed error

Comment: what is ng serve -verbose Sir?

Comment: its will get you detailed message about what happenings

Comment: how would i fix the problem based on the result of that command?

Comment: you should try to fix the errors when you get it. if you dont have error try updating npm & dependencies

Comment: its says error in ./src/main.ts , module build failed. type error cannot read property newLine of undefined